# jqGrid: grid data is not avaibale when there is a newLine character for textarea field

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with the following column defination -

```
          {
                name: 'description',
                index: 'description',
                sorttype: "string",
                edittype: "textarea",
                editable: true,
                editoptions: { rows: "5",cols:"23" },
                editrules: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
```

When I'm inserting multi line data inside the textbox, data got saved in database. But when I'm trying to reload the grid, I'm getting the grid empty.

I found the below from firebug response tab -

```
:"aa ab", "category_type":"GOVT", "description":"bb
cc", "status":"1"},{"category_id":"07", "category_name":"ab123", "category_type":"GOVT",        
"description"
```

Here the data

```
bb
cc
```

was inserted by me for the description field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself.
I have replaced the new line character with 
 html -

```
description.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "<br/>")
```

And in javascript side, for the column model add the following formatter -

```
formatter: function(cellValue, options,
                        rowObject) 
{
                    console.log(cellValue);
                     return cellValue.replace('<br/>','\n\r');
}
```